# Getting a specific random forest variable importance measure from mlr package's resample function

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, resampling, mlr

I am using [mlr](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr) package's `resample()` function to subsample a random forest model 4000 times (the code snippet below).

As you can see, to create random forest models within `resample()` I'm using [randomForest](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/index.html) package.

I want to get random forest model's importance results (mean decrease in accuracy over all classes) for each of the subsample iterations. What I can get right now as the importance measure is the mean decrease in Gini index.

What I can see from the source code of mlr,  `getFeatureImportanceLearner.classif.randomForest()` function (line 69) in [makeRLearner.classif.randomForest](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr/blob/master/R/RLearner_classif_randomForest.R) uses `randomForest::importance()` function (line 83) to get importance value from the resulting object of `randomForest` [class](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/randomForest/versions/4.6-14/topics/randomForest). But as you can see from the source code (line 73) it uses 2L as the default value. I want it to use 1L (line 75) as the value (mean decrease in accuracy).

How can I pass the value of 2L to `resample()` function, ("extract = getFeatureImportance" line in the code below) so that `getFeatureImportanceLearner.classif.randomForest()` function gets that value and sets `ctrl$type = 2L` (line 73)?

```
rf_task <- makeClassifTask(id = 'task',
                           data = data[, -1], target = 'target_var',
                           positive = 'positive_var')

rf_learner <- makeLearner('classif.randomForest', id = 'random forest',
                          par.vals = list(ntree = 1000, importance = TRUE),
                          predict.type = 'prob')

base_subsample_instance <- makeResampleInstance(rf_boot_desc, rf_task)

rf_subsample_result <- resample(rf_learner, rf_task,
                                base_subsample_instance,
                                extract = getFeatureImportance,
                                measures = list(acc, auc, tpr, tnr,
                                                ppv, npv, f1, brier))
```

My solution: Downloaded source code of the mlr package. Changed the source file line 73 to 1L (https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr/blob/v2.15.0/R/RLearner_classif_randomForest.R). Installed the package from command line and used it. Not an optimal solution but a solution.

Answer (score 3):

You provide a lot of specifics that do not actually relate to your question, at least how I understood it.
So I wrote a simple MWE that includes the answer.
The idea is that you have to write a short wrapper for `getFeatureImportance` so that you can pass your own arguments. Fans of `purrr` can do that with `purrr::partial(getFeatureImportance, type = 2)` but here I wrote `myExtractor` manually.

```r
library(mlr)
rf_learner <- makeLearner('classif.randomForest', id = 'random forest',
                          par.vals = list(ntree = 100, importance = TRUE),
                          predict.type = 'prob')

measures = list(acc, auc, tpr, tnr,
                ppv, npv, f1, brier)

myExtractor = function(.model, ...) {
  getFeatureImportance(.model, type = 2, ...)
}

res = resample(rf_learner, sonar.task, cv10, 
               measures = measures, extract = myExtractor)

# first feature importance result:
res$extract[[1]]

# all values in a matrix:
sapply(res$extract, function(x) x$res)
```

If you want to do a bootstraped learenr maybe you should also have a look at `makeBaggingWrapper` instead of solving this problem through `resample`.